# Is it effective and is it kosher to perform the practice that leads to seed being spilled, but not actually spilling any?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, sexuality

That was a difficult title to figure out how to write! Well, here is the question. Spilling seed is a sin, but what about doing the same activity but stopping before spilling seed? The deeper reason I ask is that recently I heard of some non-Jewish mystical practices that supposedly involve performing this action, but turning the energy inward and back up the spinal cord, back up into the brain and the pineal gland to allegedly "open the third eye," rather than letting it release outward. I'm not implying this has anything to do with Judaism, but like some other non-Jewish mystical teachings, it's clear some other aspects of their teachings share some similarities with Jewish mystical practices, and what I think is the crucial question in such instances is to learn in which ways they are different, and to clarify what is consistent with kosher practices, and what is made up or taken from non-kosher and potentially sinful practices. Jewish mystical practices can also involve the goal of spiritual ecstasy and awakening inner spiritual vision, but when it comes to this practice I'm asking about here, I have three questions:

Are there authoritative sources that say such a practice even has the potential to work as advertised, or is this made up new age fake teachings?

Either way, spiritually effective or not, is it kosher to do if no seed is spilled? (Not asking for me *or* a friend, lol, but just to learn the halachah. And for the record this was also not the easiest to write. Somehow my first draft of "even if it's not good for anything at all, can I still do it just for fun, and is there a limit to how many times per hour?" felt like it was still implying at least some degree of personal interest, rather than the strictly educational motive that is truthfully behind the question).

What about the same practice, but doing it laying with your wife in the kosher way same as always, with the only difference being purposefully trying to redirect the energy back up the spinal cord rather than let any seed release? Would that be spiritually effective, and is it kosher to do in that case so long as you are still at other times attempting to fulfill the commandment to produce children?

Comment: This does not seem consistent with Judaism. Regarding everything aside from your final paragraph, [*Nidda* 13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.13b.2?lang=bi) indicates it would be prohibited. Additionally, it may be a faulty assumption that a person can entirely prevent הוצאת זרע by interrupting (cf. *Mikva'os* 8:3, however see *Nidda* 43a that categorizes הוצאת זרע differently with and without a הרגשה).

Comment: @Fred Normally it is no guarantee, or maybe it is never possible on a microscopic level normally, I would have to review the literature. My understanding was sometimes it is possible and sometimes not, but the question is based on the possibility it could be done using special techniques and practices involved in the whole idea.

Nidda 13b seems to completely answer the first two questions. Part 3 is still open.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.36b.14?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.57b.7?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Thank you and thank you both since I forgot to say thank you in my comment to Fred.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/sheets/429442?lang=he

Comment: Something to add the question, what I heard was semen compared to like oil, and it lights a pleasurable fire down below, or the claim is it can be redirected up to the mind and light a spiritual fire up there and open the third eye and enlighten. Clearly it's not kosher to do this yourself so the only questions left are whether the claim has any truth to it, that this really is a method for spiritually awakening, and whether there are kosher ways to do it within a marriage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BH we have Mishlei 2 and 3 to save us from folly like this.

The only appropriate use of this aspect of our neshama and guf is in the context of marital closeness and producing children. If it even is a true thing, which is highly doubtful given how quintessentially the yeiter hara is involved in this whole inyan, it will be highly destructive to a neshama because it will be a spiritual practice that feeds and is part of the impure forces of klipa (see chapters 7 and 8 of Tanya). It might also be some sort of divination or magical practice. Stay well away. [Plus I'm not sure the question of "is this method X confirmed by Torah" is considered appropriate for Mi Yodeya]

The only [proof](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/regulations-for-men/) needed to dispel the first part of the question is that halacha outrightly forbids a man from **touching** his limb, for the very reason he may come to spill seed. The only exception (maybe) is if one's wife is nearby and pure, and then the only exception is if it is an aid to going to the bathroom in a clean way, certainly no exceptions are made for practices that arouse a person!  See the links provided in the comments to your question, especially the one in Nidda.

As for the second part, it shouldn't require any proof. It's clearly immoral to use one's wife as a tool (chas vechalila) for having a "spiritual experience", and even if she supports this, it goes against halacha and hashkafa. The halacha follows the principle of "I am for my beloved, my beloved is for me" ([Shir Hashirim 6:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.6.3?lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en)) that one is never out for selfish gain, but for the benefit of the other. Everything in the bedroom is leshem mitzva. The sources for this are easy to find.

It goes against hashkafa because man is [mashpia](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/531524/jewish/Lechah-Dodi-5689.htm), a giver. A man is meant to give, not receive. Receiving is feminine and damages a man's ability to be mashpia, and is grossly unholy. If one was never taught this, one is recommended [this series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSajHqqVuJGTugMZLtrsg5pwke6Og7QVQ).

As for your comment about spiritual ecstacy:

[Mishlei 2:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.2.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en):

> כִּי־תָבוֹא חׇכְמָה בְלִבֶּךָ וְדַעַת לְנַפְשְׁךָ יִנְעָם
>
> For wisdom will enter your mind and knowledge will delight you.

There is a lofty, holy of holies spiritual ecstasy, but it is from the ecstasy of Torah learning. There are many stories of great rabbonim losing all sense of space and time while in the sugya, while developing a chiddush or a ma'amar.

---

It should be noted that there are always people who have interests in this sort of thing and find examples in agadatta or midrash to back up their claims of strange practices (and I am not talking about the OP, who has demonstrated that they are not interested for personal reasons and we believe them) - there certainly is enough out-there material that can be misused by the untrained in agadic and midrashing learning. Please pay them no heed, or at the very least take whatever they say to your Rav and find out what da'at Torah has to say on the matter. The truth of Torah will always be something holy, pure and sweet and if it isn't then it can't be authentic as Shlomo says in chapter 3:

> דְּרָכֶ֥יהָ דַרְכֵי־נֹ֑עַם וְֽכָל־נְתִ֖יבוֹתֶ֣יהָ שָׁלֽוֹם׃
>
> Her ways are pleasant ways, And all her paths, peaceful.

[Tehillim 19:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.19.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> תּ֘וֹרַ֤ת יְהֹוָ֣ה תְּ֭מִימָה מְשִׁ֣יבַת נָ֑פֶשׁ עֵד֥וּת יְהֹוָ֥ה
> נֶ֝אֱמָנָ֗ה מַחְכִּ֥ימַת פֶּֽתִי׃
>
> The teaching of the LORD is perfect, renewing life; the decrees of the
> LORD are enduring, making the simple wise;

and 10:

> יִרְאַ֤ת יְהֹוָ֨ה ׀ טְהוֹרָה֮ עוֹמֶ֢דֶת לָ֫עַ֥ד מִֽשְׁפְּטֵי־יְהֹוָ֥ה
> אֱמֶ֑ת צָֽדְק֥וּ יַחְדָּֽו׃
>
> The fear of the LORD is pure, abiding forever; the judgments of the
> LORD are true, righteous altogether

It is highly advisable to learn a lot of Torah so these ideas penetrate our heart and such questions can never arise in the first place. Still, thanks for asking and allowing us to see how pleasant and pure the Torah's ways are.

---

[Mishlei 2:1-14](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.2.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> בְּ֭נִי אִם־תִּקַּ֣ח אֲמָרָ֑י וּ֝מִצְוֺתַ֗י תִּצְפֹּ֥ן אִתָּֽךְ׃
>
> My son, if you accept my words And treasure up my commandments;
>
> לְהַקְשִׁ֣יב לַֽחָכְמָ֣ה אָזְנֶ֑ךָ תַּטֶּ֥ה לִ֝בְּךָ֗ לַתְּבוּנָֽה׃
>
> If you make your ear attentive to wisdom And your mind open to
> discernment;
>
> כִּ֤י אִ֣ם לַבִּינָ֣ה תִקְרָ֑א לַ֝תְּבוּנָ֗ה תִּתֵּ֥ן קוֹלֶֽךָ׃
>
> If you call to understanding And cry aloud to discernment,
>
> אִם־תְּבַקְשֶׁ֥נָּה כַכָּ֑סֶף וְֽכַמַּטְמוֹנִ֥ים תַּחְפְּשֶֽׂנָּה׃
>
> If you seek it as you do silver And search for it as for treasures,
>
> אָ֗ז תָּ֭בִין יִרְאַ֣ת יְהוָ֑ה וְדַ֖עַת אֱלֹהִ֣ים תִּמְצָֽא׃
>
> Then you will understand the fear of the LORD And attain knowledge of
> God.
>
> כִּֽי־יְ֭הוָה יִתֵּ֣ן חָכְמָ֑ה מִ֝פִּ֗יו דַּ֣עַת וּתְבוּנָֽה׃
>
> For the LORD grants wisdom; Knowledge and discernment are by His
> decree.
>
> יִצְפֹּ֣ן לַ֭יְשָׁרִים תּוּשִׁיָּ֑ה מָ֝גֵ֗ן לְהֹ֣לְכֵי תֹֽם׃
>
> He reserves ability for the upright And is a shield for those who live
> blamelessly,
>
> לִ֭נְצֹר אָרְח֣וֹת מִשְׁפָּ֑ט וְדֶ֖רֶךְ חֲסִידָ֣יו יִשְׁמֹֽר׃
>
> Guarding the paths of justice, Protecting the way of those loyal to
> Him.
>
> אָ֗ז תָּ֭בִין צֶ֣דֶק וּמִשְׁפָּ֑ט וּ֝מֵישָׁרִ֗ים כָּל־מַעְגַּל־טֽוֹב׃
>
> You will then understand what is right, just, And equitable—every good
> course.
>
> כִּֽי־תָב֣וֹא חָכְמָ֣ה בְלִבֶּ֑ךָ וְ֝דַ֗עַת לְֽנַפְשְׁךָ֥ יִנְעָֽם׃
>
> For wisdom will enter your mind And knowledge will delight you.
>
> מְ֭זִמָּה תִּשְׁמֹ֥ר עָלֶ֗יךָ תְּבוּנָ֥ה תִנְצְרֶֽכָּה׃
>
> Foresight will protect you, And discernment will guard you.
>
> לְ֭הַצִּ֣ילְךָ מִדֶּ֣רֶךְ רָ֑ע מֵ֝אִ֗ישׁ מְדַבֵּ֥ר תַּהְפֻּכֽוֹת׃
>
> It will save you from the way of evil men, From men who speak
> duplicity,
>
> הַ֭עֹ֣זְבִים אָרְח֣וֹת יֹ֑שֶׁר לָ֝לֶ֗כֶת בְּדַרְכֵי־חֹֽשֶׁךְ׃
>
> Who
> leave the paths of rectitude To follow the ways of darkness,
>
> הַ֭שְּׂמֵחִים לַעֲשׂ֥וֹת רָ֑ע יָ֝גִ֗ילוּ בְּֽתַהְפֻּכ֥וֹת רָֽע׃
>
> Who
> rejoice in doing evil And exult in the duplicity of evil men,

Comment: Thank you very much Rabbi